# How to change a chart type in Windows forms

Tags: c#

So this is my current program. I'v been trying out a lot of things to change the type of my new "Input" + c serie, but I just couldnt do it. Thanks for your help!

```
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace _Graph
{
public partial class FrmMain : Form
{
    public FrmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    int c = 0;
    private void Btngen_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        double a = double.Parse(Txba.Text);
        double y = 0;
        c++;
        chart1.Series.Add("Input " + c);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            y = System.Math.Pow(a, i);
            chart1.Series["Input " + c].Points.AddXY(i, y);

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you try doing a search on google first, because there are a ton of results.  https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/chart/chart-types

Comment: yeah like I said I tried a lot but somehow I messed up because it never worked. Maybe I'm missing some libraries I dont know..

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  THanks.

Comment: Obviously it is : `chart1.Series["Input " + c].ChartType = ...`. Always look at the docs first..